# Server-side Fetchxml returns different results

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, fetchxml

One of our procedures lets users bulk-insert related records by picking a view and then hitting a ribbon button. The form is saved, a flag is set, and a plugin then does its job.

We are using a subgrid with a view selector to let users pick or create their own views on the fly. Once a view is selected, the number of results (provided is lte 5k) is shown.

When a plugin runs the very same fetchxml server side (Retrieve of userquery or savedquery, then Retrieve + FetchExpression), the results change. We get not only a different number of records but also some records are different.

We concluded that the issue has to do with timezones. Some filters included "on-or-after" operators along with date values. 
Example:

```xml
<filter type="and">
  <condition attribute="modifiedon" operator="on-or-after" value="2011-01-01" />
  <condition attribute="modifiedon" operator="on-or-before" value="2011-12-31" />
</filter>
```

The plugin ran as admin. Changing the plugin user has no effect - as if the current user timezone is not considered when pulling out records from the CRM using a FetchExpression.

How can I ensure that a fetchxml expression returns the same results client-side and server-side?

Probably related: [MSDN thread](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/crmdevelopment/thread/0f0e4e97-c97a-4bc9-af4a-a5f729ca30f2).

Thanks for your time.

Edit: following Daryl's suggestion, I ran a SQL trace. Results are puzzling. Dates are correctly offset for client-side queries (ran from CRM, i.e. Advanced Find) - this means the fetchxml is correctly translated using the user's timezone settings. This does not happen for the same query, server-side; the output SQL contains the date filters "as-is", with no timezone offset. I assumed the same translation happened no matter the origin of the query execution context.

Edit 2: A flag in an hidden region of code (my last debugging resort) was preventing the plugin from instantiating the service in the running user's context. Everything runs fine now. Thanks everyone for your time and your help, it's much appreciated.

Comment: Probably not, but worth confirming its not a security permissions issue. Do you see more records when you query as admin vs the user? do you have administrator security role assigned to the users you are using here?

Comment: Are you saying the two fetch statements weren't the exact same since one included "on-or-after" & "on-or-before" and the other used something else?

Comment: @BenPatterson1, both the user who first noticed this issue and my own user have admin-level permissions. thanks for your comment.

Comment: @PaulWay: to clarify, the fetchxml happens to include date operators such as the ones above. I downloaded the fetchxml from the advanced view editor, then extracted it server-side, and last I extracted it from the grid control in the form via IE debugger - they all match. the results don't, depending on where the fetchxml is executed. thanks.

Comment: @Raine ok, and to further clarify...  You running it from both locations (or specifically the same user), get different results?

Comment: @PaulWay, if I run the very same query via Advanced Find and then use this plugin procedure with the same user (mine, for instance), I get this behaviour. Thanks.

Comment: @Raine at this point, I would also test with Stunnware.  The behaviour you're seeing is probably related to the UTC format with the plugins.  Have you tried testing with a 5 hour (or your time zone) offset on the client side to match the plugin's data?

Comment: @PaulWay - I found the culprit. A flag in a hidden region of code (my last debugging resort) was preventing the plugin from instantiating the service using the running user's context. will edit the question to reflect this. many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 6):

When working with dates, always remember to convert to utc since that is how CRM stores them in the database.

The native CRM Advanced find is going to look at whatever the current user's time zone is, and convert that whatever time they enter into the advanced find to UTC before performing a SQL query.  Your plugin control will need to do the same thing. These are the steps you'll need to perform before putting the criteria in the Fetch Xml / Linq Expression / Query Expression.

1. Get the user's UserSetting.TimeZoneCode via their SystemUserId.
2. Lookup the TimeZoneDefinition.StandardName for the TimeZoneCode from step 1
3. Call TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById() passing in the Standard Name from step 2 (you can combine steps 1 and 2 into a single query, but I prefer to cache the results of step three using the input from step 1 for a slight performance improvement. ie. use a dictionary with the TimeZoneCode as the key and the TimeZoneInfo as the value)
4. Use this function to get the UTC value for the time that you're going to use in your plugin query:

---

```cs
public static DateTime ConvertTimeToUTC(DateTime time, TimeZoneInfo timeZone)
{
    if (time.Kind != DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
    {
        // If the DateTime is created with a specific time zone(ie DateTime.Now), getting the offset will
        // blow chow if it isn't the correct time zone:
        // The UTC Offset of the local dateTime parameter does not match the offset argument.
        //Parameter name: offset

        // This quick check will recreate the serverLocal time as unspecified

        time = new DateTime(
            time.Year,
            time.Month,
            time.Day,
            time.Hour,
            time.Minute,
            time.Second,
            time.Millisecond);

    }
    var offest = new DateTimeOffset(time, timeZone.GetUtcOffset(time));
    return offest.UtcDateTime;
}
```

Comment: this is generally a sound advice but I'm not sure I understand how it helps in this specific case. I am not using a specific date field. I'm running a fetchxml and getting different results when run server-side. the fetchxml is unmodified and happens to contain date operators. the issue is likely the local-to-utc conversion, and I'm probably looking for ways to prevent this. thanks.

Comment: @raine I guess that I'm confused as to what you mean by run client side.  I'm assuming you're using javascript?  I'd suggest turning on tracing and ensuring that the fetch XML is correctly getting translated to a SQL query the same way that you're expecting it to.  That'll help narrow done which side is having local vs utc issues...

Comment: Daryl, when I mention client-side I mean regular CRM usage such as updating a sub-grid or running a query with the standard Advanced Find functionality. The trace suggestion is interesting, I'm going to give it a try. thanks.