# CRM 2011 Process Execution Time Confusion

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I am trying to write a workflow that will Check the Condition of a Date Time field on one of my entities. I want to determine if this Date Time is exactly 14 days ago. For example if today's date is July 16, 2012 I want to find all records with the Date Time as July 2, 2012.

I have tried playing around with the Process Execution Time, but I keep getting strange results. When I tried using "Date Time On 14 Days Before Process-Execution Time" I got 0 results on all of my July 2 records. When I tried to use 13 or 15 days before process execution time, I kept getting 0 results.

I then tried combined "Date Time **On or After** 15 Days Before Process-Execution Time" with "Date Time **On or Before** 13 Days Before Process-Execution Time" and i got 2 records: 1 for July 2 and another for July 3.

I then changed the aforementioned to "Date Time On or After 15 Days Before Process-Execution Time" with "Date Time On or Before 14 Days Before Process-Execution Time" and I got 0 records.

I am REALLY confused by these results. Does the workflow take into account the date **and** time of these records? For example, if the Process Execution Time is 7/16/2012 1:13pm, does the "On or After 14 Days" take into account the 1:13pm part? Would 7/2/2012 12:00pm be outside the search criteria whereas 7/2/2012 2pm would be inside?

Update:
After some investigation I found that the database stores timestamps in UTC, while the UI converts them to PST (for our timezone). Then I found that the "On" comparisons are using the UTC values. Which makes no sense to me. For example I have 2 records in the database that look like:

Date                                  Name

2012-06-30 06:18:29.000    Bob

2012-06-30 07:00:00.000    Henry

But in Dynamics they show up in Advanced Find as:

6/29/2012    Bob

6/30/2012    Henry

Whenever I tried to use the "On" comparisons I always seemed to get both records. When I moved the dates up or down by 1 day increments, i would get 0 records. My only conclusion is that On/On or After are using the UTC database dates, whereas the UI is presenting them as converted PST dates.

Answer (score 2):

In this case there are 2 things but you need to be aware of.

First, execution time does include the time portion and the on or before criteria conditions will take in account the time portion as well.

Secondly, you need to make sure that your'e handling UTC time correctly. Just because the time of an entity  looks like it was on July 2 from the UI, due to UTC offsets it could be a different date. So make sure you know what UTC time is actually on the record when you're trying to ensure that your query expression is operating correctly.

You are correct in your conclusion.  The UI will always display dates and times in the User's Time Zone, but the database stores all times as UTC.  Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364982/server-side-fetchxml-returns-different-results/11367508#11367508) answer for how to convert your time UTC (assuming you are running a C# portion to your workflow)