# QueryScheduleRequest not working in Microsoft CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I basically want to check if a particular user is free in a provided time range using **QueryScheduleRequest**. For this I am using the following piece of code to retrieve available timings of the user on today's date:

```
QueryScheduleRequest scheduleRequest = new QueryScheduleRequest
            {
                ResourceId = userResponse.UserId,
                Start = DateTime.Today,
                End = DateTime.Today,
                TimeCodes = new TimeCode[] { TimeCode.Available}
            };
QueryScheduleResponse scheduleResponse =    (QueryScheduleResponse)serviceProxy.Execute(scheduleRequest);
```

However, I am not getting proper response in scheduleResponse as seen in CRM service calendar. The start and end dates are also getting changed in the response. For eg, say I enter Start and End date as 12th in scheduleRequest but in scheduleResponse they get changed to 12th and 13th respectively. I have checked that I am referring the correct user.

This is how the user's schedule looks like in CRM (Work Hours:10am to 7pm):
[image]

And this is how the result in scheduleResponse looks like:

[image]

Observe the dates and schedule getting changed. Is there any other way in which I can achieve this functionality?

Comment: I think the issue you have run into is because of the timezone difference between your client and the crm server (wherever that is). [This](http://mscrmonline.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/time-zone-setting-in-microsoft-crm/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944111/datetime-plugin-crm-2011) might be places to start.

Answer (score 0):

Basically Dynamics CRM stores all dates in the database as **UTC time**.Crm Users has to convert into Users LocalTime.

After getting scheduleResponse. You can Use the below Code to get User **Start time** and **End Time**.

```
QueryScheduleResponse scheduleResponse = (QueryScheduleResponse)service.Execute(scheduleRequest);
                                    foreach (var getTimings in scheduleResponse.TimeInfos)
                                   {
                                       DateTime startTime =Convert.ToDateTime(getTimings.Start.Value.ToLocalTime());
                                       DateTime endTime = Convert.ToDateTime(getTimings.Start.Value.ToLocalTime());
                                   }
```

Note:we have **ExpandCalendarRequest** Class also to Retrieve User Available Timings